# Structuremap does not work on MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, structuremap, asp.net-mvc-4

I've used `StructureMap` in MVC2/3 many times without any concern, but I guess handling IoC is different in MVC4.
When i used `StructureMap` for handling IoC in MVC4 I get the following exception.:

### No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Why?
I have not found any correct result in google except this: [IoC Not Working In MVC4](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/725313/ioc-not-working-in-mvc4)
These is my IoC classes:

```
public static class IoC {
    public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                        {
                            //scan.Assembly("DLL.Core");
                            scan.Assembly("DLL.CMS");
                            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                        });
                        x.For<IDbContext>().Use<ModelEntities>();
                        x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
                        x.For<IHttpControllerActivator>();
                        x.For<IController>();
                    });

        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

And SmDependencyResolver is:

```
    public class SmDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public SmDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        if (serviceType == null) return null;
        try
        {
            return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface
                     ? _container.TryGetInstance(serviceType)
                     : _container.GetInstance(serviceType);
        }
        catch
        {

            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType).Cast<object>();
    }
}
```

And my error is:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the                stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> ```
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
> ```
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean
>   fillCache) +241    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic) +69
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +67
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'Parsian.Web.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.MemberController'. Make sure
>   that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +182
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +74
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +196    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__2() +49    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   +13    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func)
>   +124    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8862676    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Thanks for correct answers.

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Do you set the `SmDependencyResolver` as `DependencyResolver` in the Global.asax or in the `PreApplicationStartMethod`?. Because I've just created a MVC4 project with the [StructureMap.MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC3) nuget package and it works as excepted...

Comment: i dont want use this package, I add only structuremap package (dll) to project with nuget.

Comment: Just use the DefaultControllerFactory.

Comment: What is the meaning?How do this?

Comment: Make sure you are wiring up the DependencyResolver in your global.asax, and that you are mapping the appropriate resolvers in your SM setup.  That error is usually what you get when you don't do one of those two things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

oops.I found an emergency solution :) Try to implement a class from `IControllerActivator`

```
public class StructureMapControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
   private IContainer _container;
    
   public StructureMapControllerActivator(IContainer container)
   {
       _container = container;
   }
    
   public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   {
       return _container.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
   }
}
```

and then register it to the IoC class:

```
 x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();
```

and then enjoy it.
Good luck

Comment: This should not be needed with Structuremap. See [this blog](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/do-not-implement-icontrolleractivator-in-asp.net-mvc-3) post on why the IControllerActivator extension point is in MVC3+.

Comment: While `IControllerActivator` is not technically needed, you may still want one, at least durring development. Why? Well because if you don't and your DI container throws an error, then MVC will eat the error, and try again with `Activator.CreateInstance`, which could yield an error like the one above. This makes it hard to determine what went wrong. :-(

Answer (score 3):

If you remove any old configuration for structuremap and install [structurmap.mvc4 from nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC4) then configure your IoC container, you don't have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

try adding this class as your ControllerFactory, I've actually seen the error above in MVC3 and this usually fixed it for me

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            return (controllerType == null)
                       ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
                       : ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very old way of implmenting dependency injection in MVC... Crica MVC1-2.  MVC 3 and 4 implement IDependencyResolver as an interface to your IOC Container.

Comment: @reach4thelasers Is IDependencyResolver responsible for injecting dependencies into my controller constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Using `StructureMap.MVC5.Update` I had to do this or else the nested IContainer was already disposed (weird) :

```
public class StructureMapControllerActivator : IControllerActivator
{
    public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        return StructuremapMvc.StructureMapDependencyScope.GetInstance(controllerType) as IController;
    }
}
```